# Solution of a system of first order coupled PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a system of coupled PDEs 
$$\dot{x}+y\prime+xy-y=0\tag{1}$$
$$\dot{y}+x\prime+x+xy=0$$ 
Where $x=x(s,t)$, and $y=y(s,t)$.

$\dot{()}$ represents the derivative w.r.t time $'t'$ and
$()\prime$ refers to derivative w.r.t. the space variable $'s'$.

The initial conditions are given by,
$$x(s,0)=s, y(s,0)=1$$ 
I need to solve these equations analytically (if possible) or numerically.

**What I have done:**

The system of equations can be written in matrix form as:

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right]\dot{\begin{Bmatrix} 
x \\ 
y\\  
\end{Bmatrix}}+ \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right]\begin{Bmatrix} 
x \\ 
y\\  
\end{Bmatrix}^\prime+\begin{Bmatrix} 
xy-y \\ 
x+xy\\  
\end{Bmatrix}=0$$ 
Which can be written as: 
$$A\dot{U}+BU^\prime+f(U)=0 \tag{2}$$ 
Where, 
$$U=\begin{Bmatrix} 
x \\ 
y\\  
\end{Bmatrix}, A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right], B=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right], f(U)= \begin{Bmatrix} 
xy-y \\ 
x+xy\\  
\end{Bmatrix}$$ 
Rewriting the system by multiplying with ${A}^{-1}$, 
$$\dot{U}+{A}^{-1}BU^\prime+{A}^{-1}f(U)=0\tag{3}$$ 
Diagonalizing ${A}^{-1}B$ 
$${A}^{-1}B=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right]=SD{S}^{-1}$$ 
Where, 
$$S=\left[\begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right], D=\left[\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$$ 
Where $D$ represents the diagonal matrix with its diagonal elements as the **Eigen values**. 
Since the Eigen values are **real and distinct**, the system of PDEs is **hyperbolic**.

Rewriting Equation (3), 
$$\dot{U}+SD{S}^{-1}U^\prime+{A}^{-1}f(U)=0$$ 
Multiplying with $S^{-1}$ throughout 
$$S^{-1}\dot{U}+D{S}^{-1}U^\prime+S^{-1}{A}^{-1}f(U)=0\tag{4}$$ 
If we introduce a new vector, $V=\begin{Bmatrix} 
v_1 \\ 
v_2\\  
\end{Bmatrix}=S^{-1}U$, Equation(4) becomes: 
$$\dot{V}+DV^\prime+S^{-1}{A}^{-1}f(SV)=0\tag{5}$$ 
In Equation(5), the matrix $D$ decouples the derivative terms. But the term $S^{-1}{A}^{-1}f(SV)$ is causing problem. It is not allowing the decoupling, as shown in Equation (6). The system of equations become: 
$$\dot{\begin{Bmatrix} 
v_1 \\ 
v_2\\  
\end{Bmatrix}}+ \left[\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right]\begin{Bmatrix} 
v_1 \\ 
v_2\\  
\end{Bmatrix}^\prime+\begin{Bmatrix} 
v_2 \\ 
{v_2}^2-{v_1}^2-v_1\\  
\end{Bmatrix}=0\tag{6}$$

Can I use **the method of characteristics** to solve this system? If not please suggest any other method.

How should I proceed to solve this system if $f(U)$ can be any nonlinear functions in $x$ and $y$? Please help...

Comment: It is often the case that *systems of balance laws* don't decouple (it is even more likely here since $f(U)$ is non-linear w.r.t. $U$). In this case, the method of characteristics isn't very useful...

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Since the method of characteristics is not useful for the problem, I should try other methods. Now I am considering method of lines to convert the system into ODEs. Can you please suggest a method which can be a better way to solve the given problem

Comment: Sure! I'd suggest the use of [finite volume schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method)